# What is the difference between when I run a spark application using spark-submit and java -cp?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Case 1:

> spark-submit --class main.Test --master local[4] /path/Test.jar

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Test")
    .getOrCreate();
```

Case 2:

> java -cp /path/Test.jar com.main.Test

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Test")
    .master("local[4]")
    .getOrCreate();
```

What is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no major difference. The issues you may find are more deployment-related.

Case 1: you may need a super/uber jar to make sure everything is together.

Case 2: in some cases, like AWS EMR (at least until recently), you can't use:

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Test")
    .master(<emr cluster's ip>)
    .getOrCreate();
```

Typically case 1 is development and case 2 is deployment. But there is no obligation.

Hope it helps...